# Best ROS distribution for Universal robot

Tags: ubuntu, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am starting a project with a UR5 (CB3) from Universal Robot and I would like to use ROS for this.
I have a linux based laptop, with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
What is the best ROS distribution to work with the Universal Robot packages?
I see that the newest distribution is Noetic, does that mean this is the best to use with the ur5?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358058/best-ros-distribution-for-universal-robot/) by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have a linux based laptop, with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Regardless of your question, your choice of OS limits you to ROS Kinetic, as that's the only ROS version supported on Ubuntu Xenial (ie: `16.04`). See [REP-3: Target Platforms/Platforms by Distribution/Kinetic Kame (May 2016 - May 2021)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on 2020-07-28**:
Okay thanks. So I have the option to keep Ubuntu Xenial and install ROS Kinetic, or I can upgrade to Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) and install ROS Noetic. Would u suggest the last option?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-28**:\

> So I have the option to keep Ubuntu Xenial and install ROS Kinetic, or I can upgrade to Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) and install ROS Noetic

Is Melodic on Bionic not an option?

**Comment by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on 2020-07-28**:
Yes that is also an option, I want to use the best ROS distribution for universal robot. I can reinstall my laptop to get the correct Ubuntu version.

**Comment by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on 2020-08-04**:
Is Melodic or Boinic a better option for the ur5 (Universal Robots)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-04**:
Melodic is the name of a ROS release. Bionic is the name of an Ubuntu release.

You can install Melodic on Bionic, but your question as-is doesn't really have an answer.

I would suggest to install Ubuntu Bionic and then ROS Melodic, to get started.

**Comment by [lrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/56958/lrk/) on 2020-08-04**:
Oh excuse me I typed 'or'  i.o. 'on'. Thank you, I will install Ubuntu Bionic and ROS Melodic.